# How to count variable words and echo it with different styles if number is other than expected

Tags: php, variables, count

Let's say, that I have a variable which has a random number of words. For example, if variable has 2 words, then it should be `echo` with one style. If has 3 words, then `echo` it with other style... etc...

```
$mywords = "some sentence goes here";

if ... { // what to do next?

        echo '<span style="style1">$mywords</span>';
}

   elseif ... // ?
```

Ideas on how to accomplish this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `str_word_count()` :

```
$mywords = "some sentence goes here";
$countWords = str_word_count($mywords);


if ($countWords === 3) {

} elseif($countWords === 4) {
  //This gets executed
} else {

}
```

Comment: Thanks, thats working. I will accept answer in 8 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

You can use explode to convert the string to an array based on the delimiter(A space in your case) & than count the number of element in the array.

A sample example:

```
$test = explode(" ", $inputString);
echo count($test);
```